# Can't grab a phone number from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to fetch a phone number from a webpage but I can't find any idea as to how I can grab that as the number is in image.

[Website link](https://dubai.dubizzle.com/motors/used-cars/hyundai/accent/2018/6/8/hyundai-accent-excellent-condition-still-u-2/?back=L21vdG9ycy91c2VkLWNhcnMvP3BhZ2U9MzUmcHJpY2VfX2d0ZT0mcHJpY2VfX2x0ZT0meWVhcl9fZ3RlPSZ5ZWFyX19sdGU9JmtpbG9tZXRlcnNfX2d0ZT0ma2lsb21ldGVyc19fbHRlPSZzZWxsZXJfdHlwZT1PVyZrZXl3b3Jkcz0maXNfYmFzaWNfc2VhcmNoX3dpZGdldD0wJmlzX3NlYXJjaD0xJnBsYWNlc19faWRfX2luPSZwbGFjZXNfX2lkX19pbj01OSUyQzkwJTJDMTMzJTJDMTA2JTJDMTg4JTJDJmFkZGVkX19ndGU9JmF1dG9fYWdlbnQ9&shownumber)

This is how that number is displayed on that page:

[image]

I've written so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "use_above_link"

def get_phone_number(link):
    resp = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")
    phone = soup.select_one("img.phone-num-img")['src']
    print(phone)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  get_phone_number(url)
```

***How can I scrape this very phone number from that webpage?***

Comment: I think the point of making in an image was so that you don't. But you could always try OCR techniques.

Comment: I can only try with OCR once there is any valid image url but I don't find one @Norrius.

Comment: download the image and feed it to google glasses?

Comment: How do you download when you don't have a link to make use of @Robert Cotterman?

Comment: I think you need to modify you question once, as it's quite unclear for your comments what your motives are?

Comment: Extracting the phone number and thats it @Vasu Deo.S.

Comment: do we have the link for the website or not?

Comment: The link is already there within my post. Just look around.

Comment: The image has a unique name for it, you could easily write the script to find and download that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

The clues start with the following html that indicates the tel number likely has a base64 encoding

[image]

The base64 encoded value of that tel number is `MDA5NzE1MjE3NjQ4MDY=`. This value is not present on that page but is present at one of the other urls you can extract from the initial page html.

Issue a second request to that url, target the `[data-tel]` attribute, which  is where the encoded string is stored, extract the base64 encoded string and decode.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import base64

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://dubai.dubizzle.com/motors/used-cars/hyundai/accent/2018/6/8/hyundai-accent-excellent-condition-still-u-2/?back=L21vdG9ycy91c2VkLWNhcnMvP3BhZ2U9MzUmcHJpY2VfX2d0ZT0mcHJpY2VfX2x0ZT0meWVhcl9fZ3RlPSZ5ZWFyX19sdGU9JmtpbG9tZXRlcnNfX2d0ZT0ma2lsb21ldGVyc19fbHRlPSZzZWxsZXJfdHlwZT1PVyZrZXl3b3Jkcz0maXNfYmFzaWNfc2VhcmNoX3dpZGdldD0wJmlzX3NlYXJjaD0xJnBsYWNlc19faWRfX2luPSZwbGFjZXNfX2lkX19pbj01OSUyQzkwJTJDMTMzJTJDMTA2JTJDMTg4JTJDJmFkZGVkX19ndGU9JmF1dG9fYWdlbnQ9&shownumber')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    link = 'https://dubai.dubizzle.com' + soup.select_one('[media][href$=shownumber]')['href']
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    encoded = soup.select_one('[data-tel]')['data-tel']
    tel = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    print(tel)
```

---

**Notes:**

It looks like the rel alternate (the second url) is simply a mobile device url and that you can issue just one request and substitute in /m/ into the original url i.e.

```
https://dubai.dubizzle.com/m/motors/used-cars/hyundai/accent/2018/6/8/hyundai-accent-excellent-condition-still-u-2/?back=L21vdG9ycy91c2VkLWNhcnMvP3BhZ2U9MzUmcHJpY2VfX2d0ZT0mcHJpY2VfX2x0ZT0meWVhcl9fZ3RlPSZ5ZWFyX19sdGU9JmtpbG9tZXRlcnNfX2d0ZT0ma2lsb21ldGVyc19fbHRlPSZzZWxsZXJfdHlwZT1PVyZrZXl3b3Jkcz0maXNfYmFzaWNfc2VhcmNoX3dpZGdldD0wJmlzX3NlYXJjaD0xJnBsYWNlc19faWRfX2luPSZwbGFjZXNfX2lkX19pbj01OSUyQzkwJTJDMTMzJTJDMTA2JTJDMTg4JTJDJmFkZGVkX19ndGU9JmF1dG9fYWdlbnQ9&shownumber#
```

Code then simplifies to:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import base64

r = requests.get('https://dubai.dubizzle.com/m/motors/used-cars/hyundai/accent/2018/6/8/hyundai-accent-excellent-condition-still-u-2/?back=L21vdG9ycy91c2VkLWNhcnMvP3BhZ2U9MzUmcHJpY2VfX2d0ZT0mcHJpY2VfX2x0ZT0meWVhcl9fZ3RlPSZ5ZWFyX19sdGU9JmtpbG9tZXRlcnNfX2d0ZT0ma2lsb21ldGVyc19fbHRlPSZzZWxsZXJfdHlwZT1PVyZrZXl3b3Jkcz0maXNfYmFzaWNfc2VhcmNoX3dpZGdldD0wJmlzX3NlYXJjaD0xJnBsYWNlc19faWRfX2luPSZwbGFjZXNfX2lkX19pbj01OSUyQzkwJTJDMTMzJTJDMTA2JTJDMTg4JTJDJmFkZGVkX19ndGU9JmF1dG9fYWdlbnQ9&shownumber')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
encoded = soup.select_one('[data-tel]')['data-tel']
tel = base64.b64decode(encoded)
print(tel)
```

Comment: Awesomely nice solution @QHarr!!! Now go through the comments in order to realize that a sligtly tricky question always gets different type of attacks from different angles.

Comment: To be honest that alternate url is for mobile devices I think and you can issue simply one request by adding /m/ into the original url.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Use a paid OCR service**

The quickest way to solve this problem will be to use an OCR service. The downside: they are not free.

eg: Set up a google cloud project and enable the vision API. [Instructions here.](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/vision/) Then pass the image you acquired to the API and get the numbers back.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from google.cloud import vision

url = "use_above_link"
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

def get_phone_number(link):
  resp = requests.get(link)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")
  phone_src_url = soup.select_one("img.phone-num-img")['src']
  print(phone_src_url)
  response = client.annotate_image({
    'image': {'source': {'image_uri': phone_src_url }},
    'features': [{'type': vision.enums.Feature.Type.TEXT_DETECTION}],
  })


if __name__ == '__main__':
  get_phone_number(url)
```

---

**2. Use OPEN CV**

This method is going to involve you writing a lot of code yourself. The main assumption here is you are going to parse dubizzle links. If that is the case, the font for those phone numbers is standard. You will have to parse the images of each digit from 0 to 9 into recognisable curves. Then you will need to detect the curves in each image. [Detailed instructions here.](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/d45/tutorial_py_contours_more_functions.html)

You find and cut out 10 images - one for each digit. This will be your master set. Then you will need to match the images by following [the tutorial I linked](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/d45/tutorial_py_contours_more_functions.html). Depending on the position of each match, you will have to order the output from left to right.

Comment: If I found any image url to that phone number, I did not have to create this post. The thing is I can't find any url to feed whether I go for pytesseract, open cv or cloud. Hope you understand.

Comment: ok, you need to re-frame your question. The problem is not that you cannot get a number from an Image. The problem is that you cannot get an image source from a webpage.

Comment: That's not going to work so easily. There is a javascript function that is setting the image source.  In this file: https://dbzstatic-a.akamaihd.net/.dist_e0e53e7ae40ad724639e04a41a0c2924814fae37/js/top.js look for `s.attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + e.image_text)` and reverse engineer from there.